# SQL Server Replication issue with INSTEAD OF UPDATE Trigger and Column-level tracking

Tags: sql-server, replication, trigger

I’m facing an issue with SQL Server Replication and INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger.

I have a table and a trigger that looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA]
(
       [Identifier]  BIGINT         IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [Name]        NVARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
       [Description] NVARCHAR(4000) NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Identifier] ASC)
)

GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableAInsteadOfUpdate] ON [dbo].[TableA] INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS 
BEGIN

       --Obviously some code here

       UPDATE 
             dbo.TableA
       SET
             Name = t0.Name
             ,Description = t0.Description
       FROM
             inserted AS t0
       WHERE 
             dbo.TableA.Identifier = t0.Identifier

       --And here to...
END
```

The UPDATE inside the trigger update all columns, disregarding of the real updated columns in the original UPDATE query :

```
--This update will lead to a final UPDATE instruction on all columns
UPDATE TableA SET Name = 'test' WHERE Identifier = 2
```

The column-tracking option of replication article is not working because SQL Server replication internaly use COLUMNS_UPDATED() to flag updated columns in a trigger.

One solution would be to execute individual UPDATE for each column separatly like that :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableAInsteadOfUpdate] ON [dbo].[TableA] INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS 
BEGIN

       --Obviously some code here

       IF UPDATE (Name)           BEGIN UPDATE TableA SET Name = t0.Name                FROM inserted AS t0 WHERE TableA.Identifier = t0.Identifier END
       IF UPDATE (Description)    BEGIN UPDATE TableA SET Description = t0.Description  FROM inserted AS t0 WHERE TableA.Identifier = t0.Identifier END

       --And here to...    
END
```

This is obviously not a good things for performance but at least this should work. Another way would be to modify replication trigger to implement a real column data comparision logic but i’m not sure that’s a good idea…
Does someone have a better solution ?

By advance thank you for your answer and have a nice day!

Comment: See the last answer in this forum, not sure if that what your issue is.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e72f7f4c-cf0e-463e-a1f2-31eac229de20/how-can-i-replicate-triggers?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: Thank you but this is not related to my issue, your thread is talking about schema replication, mine is about data.